# react-native-notifications - Couldn't run project on Android

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I did all the things according to  [the document](https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications) but couldn't run the project on Android. Please take a look on the following image to see the errors.

[image]

And here are [the files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9jPE49WY56IWmszR0RscHNzQ00/view) that I edited based on the document.

> Note: This is just a blank react-native project installing react-native-notifications, doesn't have any lines of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 0.47 of React Native made a change to the `ReactPackage` interface which breaks libraries like `react-native-notifications`. Force the use of 0.46 until there's a version of the library that supports RN 0.47.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.47.0